# Prove that $\mathbb R\mathrm P^1$ is diffeomorphic to certain submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: manifolds, diffeomorphism

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Prove that the Real Projective Line $\mathbb R\mathrm P^1$ is diffemorphic to certain submanifold $M$ of $\mathbb R^3$ via the map $f:\mathbb R\mathrm P^1\to \mathbb R^3$ given by:
> $$f(x:y)=\Big(\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2},\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\Big)$$

It is a simple exercise show that $f$ is injective and thus $f:\mathbb R\mathrm P^1\to M=f(\mathbb R\mathrm P^1)$ must be a bijection.

Also, I can show that the Jacobian of $f$ has rank 1 respecto to the local charts on $\mathbb R\mathrm P^1$:
$$
\begin{array}{cll}
\mathcal U_1=\{(x:y)\in \mathbb R\mathrm P^1|x\ne 0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\
(x:y)&\longmapsto& y/x
\end{array}\qquad 
\begin{array}{cll}
\mathcal U_2=\{(x:y)\in \mathbb R\mathrm P^1|y\ne 0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\
(x:y)&\longmapsto& x/y
\end{array}$$

**Unfortunately I am not able to find which submanifold is $f(\mathbb R\mathrm R^1)$**.

Any help?

Comment: looks like $S^1$

Comment: The image is all triples $(u,v,w)$ with $u,w\geq0,$ $u+w=1,$ and $v^2=uw.$

Comment: Why can't you just leave it as $f(\mathbb{RP}^1)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\textbf{Claim:}$ The image $f(\mathbb{R}P^1)$ is a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ lying in the plane $u+w = 1$ with center $\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$.

We will denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $(u,v,w)$ as suggested by Thomas in the comments, and derive the suggested relations. Now $u(x:y) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ and $w(x:y) = \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}$. Hence $u(x:y) + w(x:y) = 1$ for all $(x:y)\in \mathbb{R}P^1$. So, the image of $f$ has to be contained in the plane $u+w = 1$. A similar calculation verifies that the image also satisfies $v^2 = uw$.

Now rearranging the equation for the plane we get $w = 1-u$. Replacing $w$ in the equation $v^2 = uw$ and rearranging, we get,
$$v^2 +u^2 - u = 0$$
Finally, by completing the square we arrive at
$$v^2 +\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{4} $$

Comment: Many thanks! It is pretty clear now